# Implementar DomSanitizer a url api "ANGULAR"

Tags: angular

buen dia. Estoy intentando sanitizar la url de mi api con DOMSanitizer en angular 14  y poder desplegar la informacion en un dashboard, pero al hacerlo me sale el siguiente error
"ERROR TypeError: req.url.toLowerCase is not a function", como podria solucionarlo?

Aqui lo importo:

```
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Aqui hago mis variables:

```
 DashboardUrl : ("http://localhost:3050/pacient/heartRate");
 trustedDashboardUrl: any;
```

en el constructor lo inyecto y aplico bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl al url:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer ) {

this.trustedDashboardUrl =this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.DashboardUrl);
```

}

Y fuera del constructor en mi funcion llamo a la variable:

```
 getData(){
this.sub = this.http.get<hearRateValues[]>(this.trustedDashboardUrl)
.subscribe((data: hearRateValues[]) => {
  data.map((x) => {
    this.chartData[0].data.push(x.heartRate);
    this.labels.push(x.Hora);
    this.dateArray.push(x.Fecha);
    this.hourArray.push(x.Hora);

    if(x.heartRate === 136){
      this.chartData[0].backgroundColor = 'rgba(124, 218, 124, 0.993)';
    }
  })
  console.log(this.chartData);
  this.loadData = true;
});
```

}

No se que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien me puede aclarar se lo agradeceria, muchas gracias por leer, buen dia.

Comment: Simple, lo que estás haciendo mal es buscar en el lugar incorrecto, en el código de tu pregunta, por ningún lado veo `req.url.toLowerCase`. Saludos.

Comment: A que se refiere con lugar incorrecto?, no entiendo porque me sale el error req.url.toLowerCase si en ningun momento lo declare en mi codigo,, es por eso que no esta.

Comment: Búsqueda avanzada a ese variable `req`, en algún lado ha de estar, en el peor de los casos, el error que te da es error del procesamiento de `DashboardUrl`, y si en caso, tienes acceso, revisa en ese proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo esto

```
DashboardUrl : ("http://localhost:3050/pacient/heartRate");
```

Estas definiendo el tipo de la propiedad DashboardUrl, no asignándole un valor.
Sustituye los dos puntos `:` por un `=` para asignarle la string con la url. Además los paréntesis son innecesarios.

```
DashboardUrl = "http://localhost:3050/pacient/heartRate";
```

un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso funciono!!